# Convert Multiple Word documents to Separate Excel sheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy

I have a folder full of word documents I need to transfer to Excel. I need to convert multiple Word documents that basically consist out of one big table into multiple Excel sheets in one workbook.

I found the following code:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  Set xlSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFile)
  With wdDoc
    .Range.Copy
    .Close False
  End With
  xlSheet.Paste
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set xlSheet = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

It works to a point until it gives me "Run-Time error '1004': Method 'Paste' of object'_Worksheet' failed" and then stops with still a few sheets to process.

Debugging Highlights `xlSheet.Paste`.

Any idea how to fix this to run through all the word filesand copy them?

Comment: A guess, but perhaps try pasting before closing the  document? (move `xlSheet.Paste` before `.Close False`).

Comment: That is some code I wrote. It works fine for me. Most likely there is an issue with the document on which the code fails (e.g. corruption). You could get around it with On Error Resume Next, but that won't solve the underlying problem.